# qt5 : pass QList< QList > to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

is it possible to pass 2d list from c++ to qml ?

I have tried following things, but, in qml, I only can receive an generic object QVariant.
Maybe a typecast is available in QML or > ..

C++:

```
QList<QList<QString> > str2d;
emit void sendStr2d( str2d );
```

QML:

```
function handler( str2d ){
    console.log(str2d);
    console.log(str2d.count); //undefined    
}
```

Comment: try changing QLists into QVariantLists - since QList does not inherit QObject, you cannot call any of its methods from QML. Qt QML engige supports QVariantList <-> js array although.

Comment: BTW is there exist some basic type reference manual/doc of QML ? ( such as Array , not Action/Button/Canvas )

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but if you are looking for JavaScript tutorial/documentation - Qt has only QML covered, you must learn JS on your own - just like C++. (Just search for JavaScript Array API).